# Bash loop through json array using jq

Tags: bash, jq

I wanted to loop through json array, I wrote this simple script but I am getting this error

```
#! /bin/bash


m=$(jq '.items.item | length' try4.json)

for i in $(seq 1 10);
do
    jq --raw-output --arg v $i '.items.item[$v].request.text' try4.json | base64 --decode | sed '1q;d' | awk '{print $2}'
done
```

Error

```
jq: error (at try4.json:58): Cannot index array with string "1"
jq: error (at try4.json:58): Cannot index array with string "2"
jq: error (at try4.json:58): Cannot index array with string "3"
jq: error (at try4.json:58): Cannot index array with string "4"
jq: error (at try4.json:58): Cannot index array with string "5"
jq: error (at try4.json:58): Cannot index array with string "6"
jq: error (at try4.json:58): Cannot index array with string "7"
jq: error (at try4.json:58): Cannot index array with string "8"
jq: error (at try4.json:58): Cannot index array with string "9"
jq: error (at try4.json:58): Cannot index array with string "10"
```

Comment: Please share your json?

Comment: Json is too big to post, I know json is right cause when I manually iterate using this ```jq --raw-output '.items.item[1].request.text' try4.json | base64 --decode | sed '1q;d' | awk '{print $2}'``` I get correct output

Comment: Side note: `sed '1q;d' | awk '{print $2}'` is `awk 'NR == 1 '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--argjson` instead of `--arg`. That way your variable `v` becomes a number in `jq`, not a string.

```
jq --raw-output --argjson v $i '.items.item[$v].request.text' try4.json | base64 --decode | sed '1q;d' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Yes, Thankyou :)

Comment: All this including the base64 decode and extraction of first line and iterating entries can be entirely handled in jq script.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it entirely in `jq` without needing bash:

```sh
jq -r '.items[].item.request.text| @base64d | split("\n")[0] | split(" ")[1]'
```

The same commented `jq` script as a stand-alone version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S jq -rf

.items[].item.request.text |
# Base64 decode item request text
@base64d |

# Split decoded text lines and use first line
split("\n")[0] |

# Split line on space and get second element
split(" ")[1]
```